# after updating my app it doesn't match the old version

Tags: java, android, google-play

I made an app and uploaded it on play store. Then, I made some changes with the version code in manifest and some images in assets.
Now when I try to update my old application it says the signature is not the same.
How can I solve this problem?

EDIT

#### It uploaded correctly to my play store account, But doesn't want to update if i want to install it on a device that has a previous version on it

EDIT

This is what i get
https://imgur.com/a/elLvCwg

Comment: Post the exact error you're getting at the exact place you're seeing it. A screenshot would be very useful.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key [**keystore**] with which you signed your app , you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, **since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.**

:: Reply from : @Christopher Orr

Comment: i signed it with the same keystore

Answer (score 1):

If it won't update, then it must be signed with a different key.
*But* if you managed to upload it to the Play store, it must be signed with the same key. How can this be?

As Sherlock Holmes said

> "when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?"

My guess would be the version on the **device** was not installed from the Play store. It was probably installed from your IDE, using the debug key. If you found a phone where it was installed from the Play store it would work.

Answer (score 0):

the sign key must be same together.
i think you used different sign key.

Comment: please take a screen shot from your Manifest and gradle (Module:app)